# Open downloaded file on Android Nougat with File provider

Tags: java, android, file, download

Hi stackoverflow im having really hard time opening downloaded apk on Android Nougat. I know file provider needs to be used by i just cant figure out how to enter the correct path. The app either crashes or the file is not found. It always opens /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/cf.vojtechh.apkmirror/Downloads - Which of course doesnt exists. I need the app to acces the Download directory in Internal Storage(something like *Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/" + Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS + "/" + fileName*)

Any ideas? I've been looking for this all over the internet for over an hour but I just can't find it(I got to that point that i was so angry that i wanted to leave the crash there and ignore it)

**MainActivity.java**

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
                        File apkfile = new File(getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS), fileName);
                        Uri apkUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(MainActivity.this, "cf.vojtechh.apkmirror.provider", apkfile);
                        String s = apkUri.toString();
                        Log.d("HERE!!",s);
                        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSTALL_PACKAGE);
                        intent.setData(apkUri);
                        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
                        startActivity(intent);

} else {
                        File apkfile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/" + Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS + "/" + fileName);
                        Uri apkUri = Uri.fromFile(apkfile);
                        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                        intent.setDataAndType(apkUri, "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
                        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                        startActivity(intent);
}
```

**provider_paths.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <paths>
        <external-path name="Download" path="Download/"/>
    </paths>
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="cf.vojtechh.apkmirror.provider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/>
    </provider>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the [`Environment#getExternalStoragePublicDirectory()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(java.lang.String)) method instead. [`Context#getExternalFilesDir()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getExternalFilesDir(java.lang.String)) is meant to be used for files private to your app, hence the path containing your app's package name (technically this directory *is* public, but still not what you are looking for).

```
File downloads = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
```

Then you can create a `File` representation of the downloaded file:

```
File apk = new File(downloads, filename);
```